# searching for an elementary proof a complex analysis result

Tags: cv.complex-variables, riemann-surfaces, elementary-proofs

Given a function $ g $ entire on the whole complex plane $ C $, it is possible to find an entire function $f $ such that  $ f(z+1) -f(z)=g(z) $. The proof can be given using riemann surface,automorphy,covering,etc. Can anyone find a elementary proof which avoids all such things.

Comment: Section 6.3 in [Berenstein and Gay: Complex analysis and special topics in harmonic analysis MR Number=(1344448)] deals with that problem.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA: I liked the reference in the earlier comment that you just deleted.  Did you just replace it because it was very old and in French?  I think it would be nice for you to give both references.

Comment: Thank you. I just don't know how to edit. http://www.numdam.org/item?id=ASENS_1887_3_4__361_0

Comment: Is this the same as http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4434/ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $L$ be your difference operator: $(Lf)(z)=f(z+1)-f(z)$.
Consider these polynomials
$$P_n(z)=\frac{1}{n!}z(z-1)\ldots(z-n+1),\quad n=0,1,2,\ldots.$$
Simple computation shows that $LP_n=P_{n-1}$. Polynomials $P_n$ make a basis in the space
of all polynmials, because there is one polynomial of each degree. 
This allows you to find a solution of any equation with polynomial
RHS. Then perform a limit process. For the details see any book under the title
Calculus of finite differences. For example, by N\"orlund or by Gelfond.

Comment: fantastic! i was expecting an answer from you.